# Why is the last row of my array filled with random numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a 10x10 array filled with 0's and then printing it but the last row is not filling up with 0's.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int table[9][9];
int height = 9;
int width = 9;

for(int i=0; i<=width; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<=height; j++){
        table[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<=9; j++){
            cout << table[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Why does this make my last row to come out as:

```
0 9 2 9 10 9 4201024 6422336 6422420 4199045
```

Instead of 0 like the rest of the rows?

Comment: How many rows are you printing out?

Comment: you shouldn't iterate over invalid indices. 8 is the last index not 9

Comment: Your for loops go one index beyond what you have allocated in the table. The `<=` should only be a `<`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are indexed from 0. That means if you have an array of size 9, it contains indices 0-8. If you check the index arr[9], you get undefined behavior. The last index of any array in C++ is its size minus 1. In your loops, you heck the index equal to the size of the array. This is undefined behavior. Sometimes you might get a segfault, sometimes you will get numbers, but it is never defined. If you change your loops to:

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++)
```

instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
```

Then you won't see this behavior. If you want to make a 10x10 array, change your array declaration to this:

```
int table[10][10];
```

and change your for loop to iterate from 0 to 9.

Comment: @FabioTurati You're right, I updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indices start with 0. So your loop should be changed from

`for(int i=0; i<=width; i++)` to `for(int i=0; i<width; i++)`.

Currently you are printing out one additional row that does not belong to your array.

The reason why it appears to be random values is because it is actually printing out what's stored in memory at that location, this could be anything from code to actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Your array size is 10, which means your index range is from 0 to 9. You are attempting to access an array element at index 10 which is out of range. Here's what's happening.

When storage for an array is allocated, the memory locations for the elements are  contiguous, meaning that they are adjacent to each other in RAM. When you attempt to access an array element with an index that is not within the bounds of the array, you will get whatever happens to be in that particular location of RAM at that time, which could be anything.

[image]

Referencing the image above, if your array is to store **4** elements, your index range will be from **0** to **3**. So, if you attempt to access an element at index **4**, you will get a random value.

Answer (score 1):

The code defines your 10x10 array as a 9x9 array. Treating it as a 10x10 array produces a bunch our out-of-bounds accesses. `int table[10][10]` will work much better. And in general, use manifest constants for sizes:

```
const int height = 10;
const int width = 10;
int table[height][width];
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The array you are creating is of size 9x9. So while you are printing the 10th row of a 9x9 array it prints the garbage value because 10th row doesn't exist. So in order to create 10x10 array declare it in the following way `int array[10][10]`.